# How to define a private method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just started to learn Ruby. I'm confused with Ruby's `private` keyword.

Let's say I have code like this

```ruby
private

def greeting
  random_response :greeting
end

def farewell
  random_response :farewell
end
```

Does `private` only applied to the `#greeting` or both - `#greeting` and `#farewell`?

Comment: it applies to both methods....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's fairly standard to put private/protected methods at the bottom of the file.  Everything after `private` will become a private method.

```
class MyClass

  def a_public_method

  end

  private

    def a_private_method
    end

    def another_private_method
    end

  protected
    def a_protected_method
    end

  public
    def another_public_method
    end
end
```

As you can see in this example, if you *really* need to you can go back to declaring public methods by using the `public` keyword.

It can also be easier to see where the scope changes by indenting your private/public methods another level, to see visually that they are grouped under the `private` section etc.

You also have the option to only declare one-off private methods like this:

```
class MyClass

  def a_public_method

  end

  def a_private_method
  end

  def another_private_method
  end
  private :a_private_method, :another_private_method
end
```

Using the `private` module method to declare only single methods as private, but frankly unless you're always doing it right after each method declaration it can be a bit confusing that way to find the private methods.  I just prefer to stick them at the bottom :)

Answer (score 8):

In Ruby 2.1 method definitions return their name, so you can call `private` on the class passing the function definition. You can also pass the method name to `private`. Anything defined after `private` without any arguments will be a private method.

This leaves you with three different methods of declaring a private method:

```
class MyClass
  def public_method
  end

  private def private_method
  end

  def other_private_method
  end
  private :other_private_method

  private
  def third_private_method
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It applies to everything under `private` i.e `greeting` and `farewell`

To make either of them private you can make `greeting` alone private as below:

```
def greeting
  random_response :greeting
end
private :greeting

def farewell
  radnom_response :farewell
end
```

Documentation is available at [Module#private](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-private)

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 2.1 you can mark single methods as private also like this (space is optional):

```
class MyClass

    private \
    def private_method
        'private'
    end

    private\
    def private_method2
        'private2'
    end

    def public_method
        p private_method
        'public'
    end
end

t = MyClass.new
puts t.public_method        # will work
puts t.private_method       # Error: private method `private_method' 
                            #  called for #<MyClass:0x2d57228> (NoMethodError)
```